# How to create a VSPackage with a custom project type, menus and snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

Using Visual Studio 2015 SDK and `Extensibility` Project templates, I want to develop a Visual Studio Extension (`my_vs_extension.vsix`).

After installing this extension, this features should be added to the VS:

- A new project type added to the `Add new project` menu of the Visual Studio, (my_vs_language`),
- a custom menu to be added next to the Tools menu of the Visual Studio (`my_menu`)
- Custom code snippets to the snippet folder.

**Questions**

- What is the correct way to create a new project using the extensibility templates?
- How about automatically deploying the code snippets when installing the package?

**What I tried:**

I create a new Project Type then add a Custom command to it to get my custom menu, but it's not working properly. It only adds one menu command under the Tools menu, and it is even not showing up.

(Also once created, I don't know how to rename the project type.)

[image]

[image]

Also tried creating a VSIX project and adding Custom Command and Project type to it. Now the project type is not showing up. But the menu works.